# On device testing didn't response (private submission)

Tags: bixby

I submitted my capsule as a private submission and it success, and i went on try on an real device.
[image]

But when i use up all my hints noted in the capsule, and also tried the command in 'capsule interpreter training summary' and NL training, the capsule is not loaded. Bixby response with "I couldn't understand that" And i am not seeing it under "my capsule" too, what command should i use other from those to activate the capsule?

On capsule side,I had set up dispatch name, hints, target (bixby-mobile-en-US)

On phone side, bixby ver. on phone is 2.+, samsung account is in dev team.

From the docs it said, "To see your previous submissions, you can also check within Teams & Capsules". Does it refer to public or private submission or both? Cuz I couldn't see my private submission on there. But there is record in my submission history in IDE. Do i missed any step in submitting and testing my private submission?[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's a few points in your post so I'll answer them in a nested list:

- Bixby response with "I couldn't understand that"

  - This is most likely due to inadequate training. You should add more training in the training file as it will help Bixby understand the types of utterances you expect to handle. Additionally, It is a good idea to train your hint utterances as that will drastically increase the chance that Bixby will be able to handle those particular utterances.
- And i am not seeing it under "my capsule" too, what command should i use other from those to activate the capsule?

  - You do not need to use any other command. When you load a private (or public) revision in the on-device testing section of your device, the revision is loaded and the only capsule available will be the one contained in that revision. You will not see this capsule in the "My Capsules" section because the "My Capsules" section contains the capsules that have been enabled via the Marketplace. A private revision is basically a development "Marketplace" that contains only your capsule in order for you to test its functionality.
- "To see your previous submissions, you can also check within Teams & Capsules". Does it refer to public or private submission or both?

  - This refers only to public submissions. Private submissions do not show up on the Developer Center in the "Teams & Capsules" section. You can view your private and public submissions in the submissions section of Bixby Studio itself.